# Angular 2. Unclosed tags. Begin tag in parent component and close in child

Tags: templates, angular, parent-child

Is it possible to do something like that (childItems is an array):

Parent component's template:

```
....
<tr child-component *nfFor="let childItems of _items" [items]="childItems">
</tr>
```

Child component mock-up:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tr[child-component]',
    template: `
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-firstItem="first">

    <td *ngIf="firstItem==true">{{item.value}}</td>

    </tr *ngif="firstItem==false">
    <tr *ngif="firstItem==false">
        <td>{{item.value}}</td>
    </tr>
</template>
`
})
```

Obviously I'm getting errors about unclosed tags and so on... Is there any way I can break the tag? Open it in the parent and close in child?

Thanks!

Comment: Noooooooo. The tags are not just string. They represent something more important (the DOMs) and cannot just be broken into different pieces. You can't define the first part of a service in your parent and end it in one of the child components.

Comment: Any other way I can render a component without enclosing tags?